# Using default camera preview

Tags: android, camera

Currently i am using a custom layout with a FrameLayout(Preview) and 2 Buttons(Capture and Cancel), to take a picture using the Camera API.

```
setContentView(R.layout.camera_api);
final Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);

captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
          myCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
}

cancelButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
          finish();
}
```

But is there a way i can use the Device's default camera layout and track the capture and cancel buttons of it while disabling video etc..,

I only want the look of the default camera. Preview and event handlers i have them customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible the way you think of it. You can send an intent and let another camera-app do all the stuff for you. If the user has made the snapshot, the ready image is returned to you.

What you want to do is not possible because **there is no default-camera-ui**. There are many Android versions and many manufacturers with each providing a slightly different *default camera app*.

Comment: :(. Actually my problem is when the user takes a picture from my application, it gets saved on the sd card and then sent to the server. So, when user is on the preview, if he/she rotates the camera, the the image saved(also sent to server) are not proper. Can this be handled in `surfaceChanged`? AFAIK it can only handle **format or size**?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Please open another question for this issue. Each thread should be one question.

Comment: Fine will do that. Thanks a lot.